# How to return a package to its original state

Tags: centos, virtualbox, rpm

I'm running a CentOS 6 server with VirtualBox 4.2 Headless. Lately my virtualbox installation hasn't been running correctly.
The problem is that, whenever I try to do something I get this error:

```
[user@server ~]$ VBoxManage list vms
/usr/lib/virtualbox/VBoxManage: error while loading shared libraries: VBoxDDU.so
: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I believe this is happening because one of my virtual machines were not working. So, after following a forum, I added symlinks to the /usr/lib/virtualbox/components directory. After that didn't fix the problem, I followed another guide that did offer me a solution. But, when I tried to remove the links, I accidentally removed them from /usr/lib/virtualbox/ directory.
After trying to re-add them from the components directory, I get an error saying that it already exists. But, I don't know where to add the symlinks in the /usr/lib/virtualbox/ directory.
I have run

```
rpm -V VirtualBox-4.2
```

And it has yielded that I am, as I suspected, missing the dependencies that I accidentally removed. But, I'm not quite sure how to install all the missing dependencies (as there are quite a few, I would like to install them all at once.) and restore VirtualBox to its original state. Can anyone offer some advice?
I have tried just a yum install of VirtualBox 4.2, but to no avail.

Thanks

Comment: After reading deeper into the man page for rpm, there appears to be a reinstall switch, I'm going to try that.

Comment: Never `rm` when you can `mv`.  One can be easily undone, the other, not so much. :) I can't even guess at what you did, to help you undo it.  Best chance at this point is to hope you can sort it out with `yum reinstall`.

Comment: I fixed it!

What I ended up doing was  

    rpm -e VirtualBox-4.2  
  
Then I reinstalled VirtualBox, and now all is fine and dandy!

Comment: Did you find that `yum reinstall` wasn't as effective as `rpm -e; rpm -i`?

Comment: yum update  
failed every time I tried to use it.

Answer (score 4):

This command shouldn't be showing you missing dependencies.  It's showing you files from the VirtualBox box package that [do not match their RPM](http://www.sans.org/security-resources/idfaq/rpm.php) (and why.)

Before you reinstall the RPM, these files will need to be deleted, *or preferably renamed*, since the install probably will not over write configuration.  Afterwards, you can use `yum reinstall VirtualBox-4.2`.

Comment: I see. Ok, I will try doing that then.